# Accessing to nested comments in a Symfony Blog

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I'm working on a project which implements a public feed. I have a `Comment` entity which let's users to submit comments to each feed. However, I want users to be able to submit responses to the comments as well.

For that purpose I have `$response` property in my `Comment` entity. I assume that saving the response is same as with saving the comment since response is also a comment.

But, I'm not sure about how I can access to a comment without its `id` and save the response for that comment.

In my `FeedController` I save a comment like this;

```
 $commentForm = $this->createForm(CommentType::class);
    $commentForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($commentForm->isSubmitted() && $commentForm->isValid()) {
        $content = $commentForm->get('content')->getData();
        $feed_id = $feed;

        $comment= EntityBuilder::newComment($content, $user, $feed_id);

        $commentService->saveEntity($comment);

        if(!is_null($comment)){
            $this->addFlash(
                'commentsuccess',
                'Your reply was successfully posted!'
            );
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('showFeed', array('slug' => $feed->getSlug()), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL));

    }
```

Here is the Comment entity;

```
/**
* Class Comment
* @package AppBundle\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CommentRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="comment")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*
*/
class Comment
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Feed", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="feedid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $feedid;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="createdby", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $createdby;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please fill in the description")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Comment")
 */
protected $response;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updatedAt;


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createdAt= new \DateTime();
    $this->updatedAt= new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set feedid
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Feed $feedid
 *
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setFeedid(\AppBundle\Entity\Feed $feedid = null)
{
    $this->feedid = $feedid;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get feedid
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Feed
 */
public function getFeedid()
{
    return $this->feedid;
}

/**
 * Set createdby
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $createdby
 *
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setCreatedby(\AppBundle\Entity\User $createdby = null)
{
    $this->createdby = $createdby;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdby
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
 */
public function getCreatedby()
{
    return $this->createdby;
}

/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 *
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 *
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}


/**
 * Set response
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Comment $response
 *
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setResponse(\AppBundle\Entity\Comment $response = null)
{
    $this->response = $response;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get response
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Comment
 */
public function getResponse()
{
    return $this->response;
}
```

}

Even if I create another form type for responses, I'm still not sure about how I can save a response for a specific comment.

Comment: Maybe you need to implement tree structure here? than take a look at this - [doctrine extensions - tree](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recomendation is to implement a Parent/Children approach, adding a (`ManyToOne`) `$parent` field to the `Comment` entity and its inversed 
(`OneToMany`) `$children` property. Later, you could add a `CollectionType` form field into `CommentType` for `$children` property, so you might need more than one response per comment.

Don't worry about parent `id`, the `CollectionType` does the work for you.
See more about how `CollectionType` works [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).

Comment: I created the $parent, $children properties and added CollectionType form field for $children. Then I added a new comment and checked the parent_id field in the database, but it is still empty. Here is my form type.  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, array(
                'by_reference'=>false
            ));
    }
}

Comment: You might need `'allow_add' => true` too, please checks the reference for more details http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html